# Is there such hadith about women working in Musnad Ahmad?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, authenticity, reference-request, day-of-judgement

Is there such hadith in Musnad Ahmad where Prophet PBUH said that, ahead of the hour, women will enter the workforce out of love for this world?

I read it as one of the signs of the hour (day of judgement).

Comment: Please specify what you actually want your tags lead to the impression that you want us to verify whether this hadith is mentioned in the given source, how it is interpreted, and whether it is authentic. Is this correct?

Comment: Yup.. correct..

Answer (score 1):

The closest wording in a hadith to what you've mentioned appears in:

> 'Abdullah said, 'From the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, who said, "**Before the Final Hour people will single out one individual for the greeting, commerce will increase until a woman helps her husband in business, people will sever their links with their relatives, knowledge will spread**, false testimony will appear and true testimony will be concealed."'" ([Al-Adab al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/adab:1049) of al-Bukhari)

Just a comment "knowledge" in this translation is an interpretation of the translator and this version was qualified as sahih by al-Albani.

This also appears in Musnad Ahmad -see [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&flag=1&bk_no=6&ID=3676)-:

> حدثنا أبو أحمد الزبيري حدثنا بشير بن سلمان عن سيار عن طارق بن شهاب قال كنا عند عبد الله جلوسا فجاء رجل فقال قد أقيمت الصلاة فقام وقمنا معه فلما دخلنا المسجد رأينا الناس ركوعا في مقدم المسجد فكبر وركع وركعنا ثم مشينا وصنعنا مثل الذي صنع فمر رجل يسرع فقال عليك السلام يا أبا عبد الرحمن فقال صدق الله ورسوله فلما صلينا ورجعنا دخل إلى أهله جلسنا فقال بعضنا لبعض أما سمعتم رده على الرجل صدق الله وبلغت رسله أيكم يسأله فقال طارق أنا أسأله فسأله حين خرج فذكر عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم **أن بين يدي الساعة تسليم الخاصة وفشو التجارة حتى تعين المرأة زوجها على التجارة وقطع الأرحام وشهادة الزور وكتمان شهادة الحق وظهور القلم**

The bold parts are mostly identical in both a similar narration was compiled by al-Hakim from Nishapur in his al-Mustadrak -see [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=3566&bk_no=74&idfrom=8257&idto=8258)- and regarded as sahih based on the conditions of imam Muslim.

The hadith actually says that the women will go out to the market and work beside her husband and maybe work on her own or with other men according to some [variations of the hadith as mentioned in the commentary called al-Fath ar-Rabaany كتاب الفتح الرباني لترتيب مسند الإمام أحمد بن حنبل الشيباني](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32851/4937)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm aware of this hadith. But I thought maybe there's another hadith. Maybe it is fake. I don't know.

Comment: @Baz maybe if you could quote from the origin of your statement and more background information that could be helpful. As mentioned "business" is explicitly mentioned one could conclude more from that.